# jQuery UI Droppable - storing element order in input field

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, input, droppable

Link of setup: https://jsfiddle.net/7b8bqzsh/1/

Can see full working example using link above. The plan is to store the order of the links into a input field so that it can be saved to a database.

Currently have the IDs pulling into the input field, but only the latest ID is shown. Is there a way to make this an array of stored variables, shown in the order that they are in the droppable elements, separated by a comma?

Code:

```
$(".social-msl-link-label").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".social-msl-group-list",
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone"
});

var orderMSLids = [];
$(".social-msl-links-order li").droppable({
    accept: ".social-msl-link-label",
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    greedy: true,
    hoverClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        orderMSLids = [];
        $(ui.draggable).clone(true).detach().css({
          position: 'relative',
          top: 'auto',
          left: 'auto'
        }).appendTo(this);

        orderMSLids.push($(this).find('.social-msl-link-label').attr('id'));

        $(this).siblings().filter(function() {
          return $(this).text().trim() === $(ui.draggable).text().trim();
        }).empty();
        $('#msl-order').val(orderMSLids);
    }
});
```

Comment: **[Something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7b8bqzsh/2/)**?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao that works great! Thanks, I see what you've done - I thought I could get around using an each loop but it's definitely needed.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao the only other issue is when re-arranged the links once they are in the right column, it doesn't update the input field correctly. I'm wondering if this is a limitation of droppable and needs to also use sortable in order for this section to work properly. Functionality, a little like this http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Geupm/2/

Comment: Ok let me get a clarification.. So when you re-arrange it to another box, you `input` should remove previous one and take the latest one right?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao ideally, if "Link A" is in box 1 and "Link B" is in box 2, and you move "Link A" from box 1 to box 3, the input will update to: "Link B", "Link A". Does that make sense?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao the other part of is I'm currently looking into is when you drop a link into a box that already has a link, they automatically swap places. Currently they both collide into the same box, and it should only accept 1 link per box.

Comment: Ok.. Let me check on that.. give me some moments..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your jsFiddle.

as you can see, the logic I applied, is to go through all the items in the list which clones the dragged elements, so I pick them up and all in the right order.

creating an array of the ids, then do a join, sandwiching the coma.

I hope it helps you.

Your removed code:

```
$('#msl-order').val(orderMSLids);
```

My code:

```
// edited
str = [];
$(".social-msl-links-order li").each(function( index ) {
  //console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).children().attr('id') );
  var res = $( this ).children().attr('id');
  if (res) {
    str.push(res);
  }
});

var string = str.join(",");
console.log(string);
$('#msl-order').val(string);
```

[Working JSFinddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w27g3xp2/)

---

**COMPLETE WORKING EXAMPLE**

here you have complete resolve.

More code added

```
$(this).empty(); // added to remove previous content
```

[Complete Working JSFinddle](https://jsfiddle.net/en2auLwL/)

Comment: great work, thanks for your help. Understand how you've worked the join after running the each loop, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: removing the previous link works great too, thanks jjgarcia!